# How to use the urw chancery font in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I would like to install/use the 'urw chancery' font in the Libre Office Writer.

I have a limited knowledge of Linux. I've managed to install some of the Microsoft's fonts (.ttf format) that worked just fine in the Libre Office Writer.

Could someone provide me with a step-by-step guide on how to do it for the 'urw chancery' font as well?

Comment: Possibly you run into [this bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104701).

Comment: First you need to download the font, double click on the .ttf file, and press the button 'install' in the new window that will pop up.

After that, open your terminal and type:

sudo cp ~/.local/share/fonts/*.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/; 

Then type this: 

sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/*.ttf;

And finally type this:

sudo fc-cache -f -v;

This should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, I just did the following

> 1. Download the .otf or .ttf file.
> 2. Double click on it and click on the green Install button in the Popup.
> 3. (Re)Start LibreOffice and the font should be available in the font menu.

There wasn't any need for any terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for the help. all working now. Can I delete any of the arabic or Chinese fonts already on the system or do I just have to ignore them.

Comment: @user781538 You can delete default or installed fonts by installing Font Manager using the command "sudo apt-get install font-manager". You can also delete them manually but I don't know the directories for the default fonts. The custom installed fonts are in 

/usr/share/fonts
/usr/local/share/fonts
~/.fonts (if installed for a single user)
~/.local/share/fonts (if installed via Font Viewer)

depending on your system and how you installed them.